# $_POST is empty when using Postman but not when submiting forms

Tags: php, post, xampp, postman

I want to use $_POST  to send info from an App to a server, but when I test with Postman the $_POST doesn't get set. I am using XAMPP and php 5.6.23:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["test"])){
$mystring=$_POST["test"];
echo $mystring;
}
else {
echo "it is not even set";
}
?>
```

This, when set with Postman, will respond:

```
"It is not even set"
```

However, when sent with this:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="http://localhost/quetzal/test.php"> 
<input type="text" name="test" value="it is set!" /> 
<input type="submit" value="CHECK MY CODE" /> </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It will give a satisfactory output:

```
it is set!
```

I've already set this in my php.ini:

```
post_max_size=80M
variables_order="EGPCS"
upload_max_filesize=80M
```

It is kinda driving me nuts...

Edit: Screens of postman usage
[image: Postman submit 1]

and Get superglobal is working fine(just replacing POST for GET (however I need to use POST in volley request, unless I use a workaround, but that is not clean):
[image: I just change POST for GET]

Comment: You're showing us the working code, but none of the postman usage which is what you're trying to fix. A couple screenshots at least should be helpful.

Comment: I edited to and show my Postman usage, but I think it is a XAMPP problem, since when I use volley to request from my App I will get the sameerror.

Comment: It appears that you are not passing them through the POST method. Remove the query string parameters and try again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are actually sending the `test` as a query parameter (retrievable within your php script via `$_GET['test']`. To add `POST` data in Postman, click on the `Body` tab and add the data there.

Comment: If only I could hug you... this doesn't explain why my android app doesn't work though... I will keep working on my android code

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this. The Postman UI is not very evident in this case. If you select "post" from the dropdown, it seems apparent you should put your values in the params table. Apparently not.

Comment: It does not even work if you do it properly. Postman has an issue, the internet is full of these reports. POSTed requests for whatever reason return an empty $_POST on the receiver end, when local.